# Proof of Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group of over $n$, $p$ is a prime number dividing $n$, then $G$ has an element of order $p$.

Step 1: Assume $G$ abelian or order $n=pm$, want to show $G$ has an element of order $p$ by complete induction on $m$.

Base case: $m=1$, $|G|=p$, the $a\ne e$ in $G$ has order $p$ works

Inductive step: let $a\in G,a\ne e$ consider $H=<a>$. If $O(a)=|H|$ is divisible by $p$ then we know $H$ has an element of order $p$. Thus we may assume $H$ is not divisible by $p$. Consider $\pi:G\rightarrow G/H$, $|G/H|=|G|/|H|=\frac{pm}{|H|}$ divisible by $p$ smaller than $n$. Thus $|G/H|$ has an element of order $p$. Thus $\pi(b)=bH$ has order $p$ in $G/H$. Then $O(b)$ is divisible by the order of its image $O(\pi(b))=p$. Now we found

Step 2: Now assume $g$ is arbitrary. Look at class equation. If $Z(G)$ is divisible by $p$, then done by step 1. Thus we may assume $p$ does not divide $|Z(G)|$ $$|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{i=1}^r\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x_i)|}$$
Thus $\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x_i)|}$ is not divisible by $p$ for some non-central $x_i$. Note $C_G(x_i)\ne G$. Assume $|G|=pm$ and argue by induction on $m$

**What's the point here???**

Base case: $m=1$ same as before

Inductive step: Assume $|G|=n$, theroem holds for all groups order $pk$. As we saw above there is a non central element $x\in G$ such that $|C_G(x_i)|$ is divisible by $p$. By inductive assumption $C_G(x_i)$ has an element of order $p$ hence so does $G$

Comment: What other theorems do you have available? Do you have the Sylow theorems, for example?

Comment: No, not sylow yet

Comment: If $|G|/|C_G(x_i)|$ is not divisible by $p$, but $|G|$ is divisble by $p$, that means $|C_G(x_i)|$ must be divisible by $p$. And as you noted, its order is strictly smaller than $|G|$. So by the induction hypothesis, $C_G(x_i)$ has an element of order $p$.

Comment: Why is there an induction on $G$ again?

Comment: Well, it's actually on $m$. You're trying to show that if $|G| = pm$ then $G$ contains an element of order $p$. This is clearly true if $m = 1$, and for general $m$ it seems natural to try an induction proof. There are alternative proofs which are non-inductive, for example [this rather slick proof by McKay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_theorem_(group_theory)#Proof_2)

Comment: The easiest is probably to just understand the first Sylow theorem, I think this proof is quite non-trivial (or as complex as the proof as the first Sylow therm)

Comment: So are there two induction going on or just one?

Comment: @Ephemeral I agree that the simplest proof is via Sylow, however some proofs of Sylow use Cauchy's theorem, so one has to be careful to avoid circular reasoning.

Comment: @ZHU You use one induction for the abelian case, and another for the nonabelian case.